# tidyr::fill() with sequential integers rather than a repeated value

Tags: r, tidyr

After grouping by `id` I wish to replace the NAs in `dist_from_top` with sequential values such that `dist_from_top` becomes c(5,4,3,2,1,5,4,3,2). I am using the one `dist_from_top` value within each `id` grouping as a seed of sorts to fill in the values of `dist_from_top` that are above and below.

`tidyr::fill()` can fill in the same value throughout the grouping, but I can't think of a way to make it increase and decrease by 1 as it fills. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- 
  tribble(
    ~id, ~mgr, ~dist_from_top,
    "A", "B",  NA,
    "A", "C",  NA,
    "A", "D",  3,
    "A", "E",  NA,
    "A", "F",  NA,
    "B", "C",  NA,
    "B", "D",  4,
    "B", "E",  NA,
    "B", "F",  NA
  )
```

An "almost there" solution using `fill()`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  fill(dist_from_top, .direction = "up") %>%
  fill(dist_from_top, .direction = "down")
```

Comment: Are you always starting with 5? I'm not sure i understand how this would work with id B specifically. There are only 4 records there. And i'm pretty sure `fill` isn't designed to fill with different values so I would think a custom `mutate()` function is likely a better choice. What if you had `c(5, NA, 1)`? What gets filled in there?

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm not consistently starting or ending with any number. Each `id` will have a list of ordered `mgr` values associated them and one of the `mgr` values will have a "seed" value that I need to fill in the adjacent values from. The answer may not involve `fill()`, but an additive version of fill was the closest I could conceptually describe my problem as.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a column that counts downwards in each group, from any starting point:

   ```
   ... %>% mutate(rn = -row_number())
   ```
2. Add the offset that is defined by the difference between `dist_from_top` and `rn` for the one row where `dist_from_top` is not `NA`:

   ```
   ... %>% mutate(dist_from_top = rn + max(dist_from_top - rn, na.rm = TRUE))
   ```

   This uses `max()` merely to pick one value, assuming there is only one value that isn't `NA`.

Both `mutate()` operations operate on groups:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rn = ...) %>%
  mutate(dist_from_top = ...) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-rn)
```

If there is an all-`NA` group, you'll see a warning.